# What's wrong with my browser JavaScript engine on jsbin.com?

Tags: javascript, html, jsbin

I am new to JavaScript. I am trying to add text into a `p` tag and targeting it using the ID. Now, using the `document.getElementById('text').innerHTML`, when I set the text that contains the `do` word, it returns the original text in the `p` tag.

```js
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML='as I add??? do';
```

```html
<p id="text" class="abc">Hello</p>
```

It is happening only with the `do` word in between.
[Here's a GIF explaining the issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R01O.gif)

[image]

I hope I am doing this right. But, there might be some quirk that is messing with me.

Comment: Submit your code in the question

Comment: It looks like jsbin is refreshing the frame. If you click `run with js`, it should output the proper value

Comment: When it switches back to "Hello," what does pressing [Run] in the top-right do?

Comment: jsbin bug. That's not your browser's JS engine.

Comment: Also, if you want to insert plain text, with no HTML, you can use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. Not a difference, but feels like more correct for me :) Greets

Comment: Thanks @You . I did that time, but it wasn't working, now it is working.

Comment: it looks like bug in jsbin. It throws syntax error like `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at  ...`

Comment: lol, it will work when you bypass `o`, like `'this is abc d\o '`

Comment: Probably the same as this bug: https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/issues/2264 (workaround in the thread)

Comment: FYI - works fine in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h7v1qb94/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by Juhana and [jsbin member](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/issues/2264#issuecomment-75839462) on github, it's a `false positive`, this can be achieved by adding `// noprotect` in the code.

**e.g.**

```
console.clear(); 
document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = 'this is abc do '; 

// noprotect
```

***p.s.*** As of now it's to work around to loop protection, until it's get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "abc a d";
```

They load this document (pretty formatted by me):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style id="jsbin-css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="text">Hello</p>
    <script>
    try {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "abc a d";
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    //# sourceURL=wecinoqeje.js
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when you use `do`, they completely screw up your code.

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "abc a do";
```

They probably think it's a [`do-while`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-do-while-statement), because they have something called "loop protection". The loaded document is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style id="jsbin-css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="text">Hello</p>
    <script>
    try {
      {
        ;
        window.runnerWindow.protect.protect({
          line: 1,
          reset: true
        });
        document.getElementById("text")
        {
          if (window.runnerWindow.protect.protect({ line: 1 }))
            break;
          .innerHTML = "abc a do";
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    //# sourceURL=wecinoqeje.js
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's a syntax error. So your code does not run.